# Android 10 device freezing in react native application

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-location

My react native application causing device freezing and restart when user approved for fine location in android 10.

**AndroidMaifest.xml** includes this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**App.js**

```
try {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
  ); 
  if (granted === 'granted') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} catch (err: any) {
  return false;
}
```

**login.js** also having permission as above.

Here is the logfile, here we can see permission granted is occurring infinite time. but same code is working good with all devices.

**logFile.txt**.

```
     11:10:18 | INFO | [App.tsx] requestLocationPermissionForAndroid()

     11:10:21 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()
    ...
    ...
    Some API calling
    ...
    ...
    11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew()

11:10:23 | INFO | [login] requestLocationPermissionForAndroidNew() granted: granted
....
....
....
looping the same.
```

**react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0**

**react-native: 0.62.2 => 0.62.2**

This issue occurring in few devices mostly android-10.

Kindly help me out of this...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this may be an issue but in your IF statement where you check if the permission is granted.  Are you sure the result is 'granted' that you should check against on all Android versions?

A safer solution may be as follows, no harm updating your code anyhow to something as below;

```
async requestLocationPermission() {
try {

  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    {
      'title': 'App Location Permission',
      'message': 'AppName is requesting access to the location services on your device.'
    }
  );

  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    console.log("You can use the location");
    return true;

  } else {
    console.log("location permission denied");
    return false;
  }

} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err)
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, will check and update.

Comment: Did the above work for you?